# Get data from firebase/react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get

How to get username field from "users" collection in document?
I just want to display in settings user username[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AVmJ.png)
[firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dstGZ.png)

I tried to get data from firestore, but it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is exactly but you can try looking at the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

If you will provide more detail then I might be able to give you direct code for the problem.

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

Above code allows you to get the data of a specific document.
the `docSnap.data()` function returns an object which contains all the fields of a document. You can use it like this for example:

```
docSnap.data()['name']
```

Another issue could be with rules. Rules can be used to setup specific conditions and allow access allow to your database when those certain conditions are followed. You could have setup rules but then later never really followed the rules in your app. I would like you to check your rules and then check the app to see if your code follows them.

Hope this helps :D